# Не могу разобраться с кодом на PYTHON 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример кода:

```
import math

def pl(a, b):
    return a + b
def mi(a, b):
    return a - b
def mul(a, b):
    return a * b
def div(a, b):
    return a / b
print("Я только развиваюсь, вот мои основные функции: \n 1) Обычные функции калькулятора(плюс, минус) \n 2) Вычисляю квадратный корень \n 3) Вычисляю факториал числа \n 4) Вычисляю гипотенузу прямоугольного треугольника, зная два его катета \n 5) Вычисление логарифма \n")

c = input("Введите то число, которое выбрали, основываясь на списках функций, про которых было сказано выше: ")

if c == '1':

    try:
        a = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    try:
        b = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    try:
        d = input("Введите математический знак: ")

    except ValueError:
        print("Введите математический знак!")
        raise SystemExit

    if d == '+':
        print("Сумма чисел равна " + str(pl(a, b)))

    elif d == '-':
        print("Разность чисел равна " + str(mi(a, b)))

    elif d == '*':
        print("Произведение чисел равно " + str(mul(a, b)))

    elif d == '/':

        if b == 0:
            print("На нуль делить нельзя!")

        else:
            print("Частность чисел равна " + str(div(a, b)))

elif c == '2':

    try:
        e = float(input("Введите число: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    print("Квадратный корень равен " + str(math.sqrt(e)))

elif c == '3':

    try:
        f = float(input("Введите число, факториал которого вы хотите вычислить: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    print("Факториал введенного числа равен " + str(math.factorial(f)))

elif c == '4':

    try:
        g = float(input("Введите длину первого катета: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    try:
        h = float(input("Введите длину второго катета: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Надо было ввести число!")
        raise SystemExit

    print("Длина гипотенузы равна " + str(math.hypot(g, h))

elif c == '5':

    j = input("А) Логарифм по основанию 10 \n Б) Логарифм по основанию 2 \n В) Логарифм по указанному вами основанию \n ")
    print("Введите русские буквы!")
    if j == 'А' or j == 'а':

        try:
            p = float(input("Введите число: "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Над было ввести число!")
            raise SystemExit

        print("Логарифм числа по основанию 10 равен" + math.log10(p))

elif j == 'Б' or j == 'б':

        try:
            o = float(input("Введите число: "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Надо было ввести число!")
            raise SystemExit

        print("Логарифм числа по основанию 2 равен " + math.log2(o))

elif j == 'В' or j == 'в':

        try:
            k = float(input("Введите число: "))

        except ValueError:
            print("Нужно было ввести число!")
            raise SystemExit
        try:
            y = input("Введите основание(можете пропустить, тогда будет вычислен натуральный логарифм): ")

        except:
            pass

        print("Логарифм равен " + math.log(k, [y]))

    else:
        print("Надо было ввести русские буквы!")


else:
    print("Что-то пошло не так(у тебя)")
```

Запускаю и вижу в консоли вот такую ошибку:

> line 94 file Калькулятор.py
>   elif c == '5'
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Но проблема в том, что я проверил код, как мне показалось очень хорошо.

Comment: 1) Исправьте в вопросе код. Выделите его и нажмите на редакторе `{}`, либо добавьте в начало и конец кода символы \`\`\` 2) текст ошибки должен быть именно текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в следующей строке (91):

```
print("Длина гипотенузы равна " + str(math.hypot(g, h)))  # <----- Забыли закрыть скобку
```

**UPD:**

Ниже есть несколько ошибок в использование библиотеки [`math`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html?highlight=log#math.log) и функции `print`, а именно в строках 106, 117, 133.

Во-первых, Вы пытаетесь сложить строку с числом, а во-вторых переменная `y` может быть не определена.

Comment: Спасибо! P.S math.log(X, [base]) - логарифм X по основанию base. Если base не указан, вычисляется натуральный логарифм.